# using elevateZoom has issues with z-index on my div which must be 2 or 3

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using elevateZoom jquery plugin and I dynamically added an image to div and tried to use the zoom on it. But because I use z-index for my div(I have to use z-indexes) the zoom lens gets behind the div.

**JavaScript**:

```js
$("#test").html('<img id="toZoom"   data-zoom-image="./icon1.jpg" width="449px" height="600px" margin="10px" src="./icon1.jpg" alt=""/>');

$("#toZoom").elevateZoom({
    zoomType: "lens",
    lensShape: "rechtangle",
    lensSize: 100
});
```

**HTML**:

```html
<div id="container" style="width:100%;height:100%;position: relative;">
    <div id="test" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:2;">
        <div></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/Regaddi/elevatezoom/commit/93028ada9814c35cd3ac0bfb037e5904c0d7a4c6

Just replace this line in the elevateZoom.js file

```
 self.zoomWindowContainer =$('<div/>').addClass('zoomWindowContainer').css("width",self.options.zoomWindowWidth);
```

with this :

```
    self.zoomWindowContainer = $('<div/>').addClass('zoomWindowContainer').css({
       "width": self.options.zoomWindowWidth,
       "z-index": 999
     });
```